# Trigger an event with one sub for multiple controls

Tags: vb.net

I have 10 panels on my form, and when you hover them, their color changes. I have 10 private subs like so...

```
 Private Sub pnl2_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pnl2.MouseHover
       pnl2.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
 End Sub
```

This code is repeated for each panel with the only difference being it's name, how can I do this more efficiently? as it is very repetitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them at the handler statement appending each by a comma. The `sender` object is the panel in question so cast it to change it's properties.

```
Private Sub pnl2_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pnl2.MouseHover, pnl3.MouseHover 'etc
   Dim pnl As Panel = CType(sender, Panel)
   pnl.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
End Sub
```